# Registered office 2016 that have used for 3 years giving not activated message

Tags: microsoft-office

I have office 2016 that I purchased and activated and have used since May 2017, was working on excel spreadsheet and program closed.got message " Microsoft sdx helper has stopped working". Tried to repair. when opening app, got message that software is not activated. Purchased access separately and it's doing the same thing. what would cause properly registered and activated working software to do this?

I haven't changed computers, same computer, same operating system - windows 8.1 To further complicate things I used a email address to register that is no longer active. tried using software to get product key from computer but no luck. I have the original reg key from the card I purchased.

Comment: You can use the product key to get the Office 2016 installer in order to reinstall Office.  There is an easily accessible Office knowledge article on this subject that provides the appropriate links.

Answer (score -1):

About the error message, please refer to CoosjeClans's reply in "[Microsoft Office SDX Helper Crash](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/microsoft-office-sdx-helper-crash/ade91695-b286-4d23-812a-a49fc72a013c)".

===========================================================================

Did you perform an Online Repair for your Office?

If yes, I guess the cause for losing activation of your Office is Online Repair. It is similar to a procedure that uninstall Office first and reinstall Office.

===========================================================================

Such as Office Home & Business 2016, Office Professional 2016 and other retailed versions users could used an email account to bind with their Office products. What's more, we should prevent forgetting this account.

As long as you log in to the email account successfully, Office could be activated. When you need to reinstall the Office, just go to "[Service & Subscriptions](https://account.microsoft.com/services/)" with your account.

If you have forgotten the bound email account, please look for any emails from Microsoft about Office in your mailbox to find back this account.

More information, please refer to "[I forgot the username or password for the account I use with Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/i-forgot-the-username-or-password-for-the-account-i-use-with-office-eba0b4a2-c0ae-472c-99f6-bc63ee2425a8)".

To confirm your key, you can enter your product key using [the Virtual support agent (English only)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/contact/virtual-agent/?partnerId=office&flowId=office-content&userInput=I%20need%20to%20download%20office%20using%20my%20product%20key). If your product key is valid, the Virtual support agent provides a link to download Office. The Virtual support agent can also let you know if your product key has been blocked and can connect you to a live agent.

When nothing helps, please [**contact Microsoft**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/contactus/) for assistance.